# Adding a floating div to a table row by click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following table:

[image: alerts]

On click of the circled blue icon there should be opened a "floating" div with some item on the right side.

This div should be responsive and be perfectly aligned with the row.

I did it by defining the floating div as `absolute` and using fixed pixel dimension.

My problem is that if i align the floating div according to the relative location of the row it get `overhidden` by the parent div. And if I make it absolute compared to the dom so its not responsive.

Any suggestions of how my divs structure should look like?

Please let me know if any info is missing?

**EDIT**:

Here is a JS-fiddle showing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/omriman12/3gv788o4/

I want the red squere to be aligned with the row(try moving the red squere to the right side of the black box)

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Its a big pile of code, thats why i didnt post it, I will try

Comment: Why does it need to float if you position it absolute? And do you mean overlapping z-index with 'overhidden'? Since that can be fixed by giving the 'popover' a higher z-index.

Comment: @user2181397 added a js-fiddle

Comment: @Shilly i tried height z-index, its not working, look at the js-fiddle

Comment: Add a working example of your code. Onclick blue icon nothing happens.

Comment: @frnt no on click, reed my edit, simply move the red box to the right, it should be aligned with the black box, that all i want

Answer (score 0):

Try this, might be you are asking for this.

```
  .main_wrapper{
  width: 79%;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.a1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}

.a2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    top: 8px;
}

.blue-wrapper {
  width:20%; 
  background-color:blue;
  display: inline-block;
  height:50px;
}
```

(or)

```
.main_wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.a1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}

.a2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 8px;
    z-index:9;
}

.blue-wrapper {
  width:20%; 
  background-color:blue;
  display: inline-block;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  top:8px;
  right:8px;
  z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: I think you didnt understand the question completly, I didnt ask for an event. try manually to move the red squere to the side, It gets overhidden, I want to align the red squere with the black. thats all(float to the right side of the black squere)

Comment: @omriman12 you want to align that at top of black, below, right or left. if top of that, then it's already aligned. For left-side set left:0; width:100%;

Comment: it should be exactly where the blue is, floating on top of him